# Adding comments via ajax to the server & current webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

I'm wanting to add new comments to a list of existing comments on page. I am wondering what would be a good strategy to do that. I am thinking if comments could be submitted via ajax but added to the HTML DOM sooner (just the text) & the alloted id will be communicated to client side from the server which would also confirm that the comment was successfully saved & should be displayed.

Is it good startegy or should I update the entire updated part fetching from server side ? What is the JSF way of doing this ?

---

Using JSF 2.1.6 with primefaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way was used by facebook earlier. But now they have switched to first way.

Also, in gmail chat, they use first way.

First update at client side, send request to server and if you do not get a successful response, show it as an error.  (No need to show anything in case of successful update)